# directly execute binary resource

Tags: c, resources, executable, portability

lpBuffer is a pointer to the first byte of a (binary)resource. How can I execute it straight away without dumping it to a temporary file?

```
HMODULE hLibrary;
HRSRC hResource;
HGLOBAL hResourceLoaded;
LPBYTE lpBuffer;

hLibrary = LoadLibrary("C:\\xyz.exe");
if (NULL != hLibrary)
{
    hResource = FindResource(hLibrary, MAKEINTRESOURCE(104), RT_RCDATA);
    if (NULL != hResource)
    {
        hResourceLoaded = LoadResource(hLibrary, hResource);
        if (NULL != hResourceLoaded)        
        {
            lpBuffer = (LPBYTE) LockResource(hResourceLoaded);            
            if (NULL != lpBuffer)            
            {                
                // do something with lpBuffer here            
            }
        }    
    }
    FreeLibrary(hLibrary);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a function built into Windows for this; your only option is `CreateProcess`, which takes an EXE file.

It's possible to parse the executable file format yourself. You'd effectively be recreating what the `LoadLibrary` function does.

Here's an explanation of how to load a DLL and call functions within it: http://www.joachim-bauch.de/tutorials/loading-a-dll-from-memory/. To adapt this for your EXE, you'd follow the same relocation and import steps. Once you're done you'd call the EXE's entry point. (The tutorial explains how to call a DLL's exported function.)

Depending on what's in the EXE you might have problems loading it directly into an existing process. For instance, your own EXE performs various Win32 and C initialization code, and the embedded EXE is likely to attempt to perform the same initialization again. If this becomes a problem, your alternative is to put the embedded EXE in its own process; then, you're back to creating a temp file and calling `CreateProcess`.

Comment: Things don't work like that. You can't just execute code which has been loaded as a resource. Relocations have to be performed. Imports have to be resolved.

Comment: Things could work like that, hence my "what's your format" question. The OP doesn't mention what's in the binary resource.

Comment: @wj32 @Bubblegun I've rewritten my answer based on this new information

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll check the tutorial

Answer (score 1):

If the resource is a [PE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Executable) file, then is no way AFAIK. If it is a simple compiled procedure try [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32133/tim-robinson)'s trick.

**Edit:**
After [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/32133/tim-robinson)'s answer update, it the most complete answer.