# How to execute file from resource?

Tags: c++, windows

I have a program which has two additional .exe files as resource. I know i can use `FindResource`, `LoadResource`, and `LockResource` and after that i can create the two file and execute them. Is it possible to execute a resource file from memory? I mean without creating the files on the file system? If i know it correctly, then it is possible somehow in C#. It can write the file to memory stream and execute it from there. How do i do that in C++?

Thanks!

Comment: Something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529080/directly-execute-binary-resource